# Bug in Android Studio 4.2 beta 2(Android Stuido Template not working)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-4.2

After Updating Android Studio 4.2 beta 2, unable to create Templates like Blank Fragment, MapFragment, Model Fragment, and Bottom Sheet Fragment, and for Activity also.

I don't know what will be the problem, I have done a sync project with Gradle files and invalidate caches restart nothing is helping me. I can able to create normal kotlin or java class. unable to create Templates like fragment( with ViewModel).

what will be the issue, how to resolve or revert back to normal working condition.